# How to force Theano to do softmax column-wise?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, theano, softmax

I have a 2D array and I would like to apply the softmax function column wise. It try the following:

```
value = numpy.array([[1.0,2.0], [3.0,9.0], [7.0,1.0]], dtype=theano.config.floatX)
m = theano.shared(value, name='m', borrow=True)
y = theano.tensor.nnet.softmax(m)
print y.eval()
```

As a result I get the following output:

```
[[ 0.26894142  0.73105858]
 [ 0.00247262  0.99752738]
 [ 0.99752738  0.00247262]]
```

Which means that the operation has been applied row wise. Is there a way to force Theano to do softmax column wise?

Answer (score 3):

> Which means that the operation has been applied row wise

Which is what it is designed to do:
http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/nnet/nnet.html#theano.tensor.nnet.nnet.softmax

Transposing the array will get your expected result. Not knowing Theano this is a bit of a guess:

```
y = theano.tensor.nnet.T.softmax(m)
```

or:

```
y = theano.tensor.T.nnet.softmax(m)
```

Reference: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor._tensor_py_operators.T

Comment: did it help? What is the actual syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: transpose

```
>>> import theano as th
>>> T = th.tensor
>>> x = th.tensor.matrix()
>>> y = T.nnet.softmax(x.T).T
>>> fn = th.function([x],y)
>>> fn([[1.,2.],[1.,3.]])
array([[ 0.5       ,  0.26894143],
       [ 0.5       ,  0.7310586 ]], dtype=float32)
```

For tensors rank >= 3, transpose needs specify axes.

```
#this perform softmax on 3rd dimension
x = tensor4()
T.nnet.softmax(x.transpose(0,1,3,2)).transpose(0,1,3,2)
```